# Convert denormalized or flat data to hierarchical Java Object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, grouping

This is what tried I did to convert a denormalized or flat data to hierarchical Java Object?

Here is the input, output and code, (question is at the bottom)

INPUT:

```
[ {
  "countryName" : "USA",
  "stateName" : "FL",
  "cityName" : "Miami"
}, {
  "countryName" : "USA",
  "stateName" : "FL",
  "cityName" : "Doral"
}, {
  "countryName" : "India",
  "stateName" : "Tamilnadu",
  "cityName" : "Chennai"
}, {
  "countryName" : "India",
  "stateName" : "Karnataka",
  "cityName" : "Bangalore"
} ]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ {
  "countryName" : "USA",
  "states" : [ {
    "stateName" : "FL",
    "cities" : [ {
      "cityName" : "Miami"
    }, {
      "cityName" : "Doral"
    } ]
  } ]
}, {
  "countryName" : "India",
  "states" : [ {
    "stateName" : "Karnataka",
    "cities" : [ {
      "cityName" : "Bangalore"
    } ]
  }, {
    "stateName" : "Tamilnadu",
    "cities" : [ {
      "cityName" : "Chennai"
    } ]
  } ]
} ]
```

CODE:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import lombok.Data;

public class Normalizer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final var objectWriter = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();

    Tuple t1 = Tuple.of("USA", "FL", "Miami");
    Tuple t2 = Tuple.of("USA", "FL", "Doral");
    Tuple t3 = Tuple.of("India", "Tamilnadu", "Chennai");
    Tuple t4 = Tuple.of("India", "Karnataka", "Bangalore");

    List<Tuple> tuples = List.of(t1, t2, t3, t4);
    
    System.out.println("INPUT:\n" + objectWriter.writeValueAsString(tuples));
    
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    
    final var countries = normalize(tuples);
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:\n" + objectWriter.writeValueAsString(countries));
  }
  
  public static Set<Country> normalize(List<Tuple> tuples) {
    System.out.println("Step 1: Grouping");
    final var map = tuples.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Country::of, groupingBy(State::of, mapping(City::of, toSet()))));

    System.out.println("Step 2: Creating Object Hierarchy");
    Set<Country> countries = new HashSet<>();
    map.forEach((country, value) -> {
      countries.add(country);

      Set<State> states = new HashSet<>();
      value.forEach((state, value1) -> {
        state.setCities(value1);
        states.add(state);
      });
      country.setStates(states);
    });
    
    return countries;
  }

  @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
  public static class Tuple {

    private String countryName;
    private String stateName;
    private String cityName;

    public static Tuple of(String countryName, String stateName, String cityName) {
      Tuple t1 = new Tuple();
      t1.setCountryName(countryName);
      t1.setStateName(stateName);
      t1.setCityName(cityName);
      return t1;
    }
  }

  @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
  public static class Country {

    private String countryName;
    private Set<State> states = new HashSet<>();

    public static Country of(Tuple tuple) {
      Country country = new Country();
      country.setCountryName(tuple.getCountryName());
      return country;
    }
  }

  @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
  public static class State {

    private String stateName;
    private Set<City> cities = new HashSet<>();

    public static State of(Tuple tuple) {
      State state = new State();
      state.setStateName(tuple.getStateName());
      return state;
    }
  }

  @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
  public static class City {

    private String cityName;

    public static City of(Tuple tuple) {
      City city = new City();
      city.setCityName(tuple.getCityName());
      return city;
    }
  }
}
```

There are 2 steps in normalize method, is there a way to get this in one step. Like, is there a way to get it just by using Java 8+ Collectors methods?

Comment: your second step could be written as `Set<Country> countries = map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new Country(e.getKey(), e.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(en -> new State(en.getKey(),
                                    en.getValue())).collect(toSet())))
                    .collect(toSet());`... this could also be implemented via `collectingAndThen` with grouping and then transforming to objects.